# Computing average return on negative returns (gemoetric mean)

Tags: finance, average

So let's say a portfolio created a loss (leveraged portfolio) of $104\%$ in six months. What would be the average return be per month?

My guess would be $(1 + 1.04)^{\frac{1}{6}} = 1.126$, so my portfolio would create a return of $-12.6\%$ a month.

Is this correct or am I overlooking something?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot lose more than $100\%$.

Comment: @callculus If it's a leveraged portfolio then you can.

Comment: Then show a numerical example, please. It shouldn't be so difficult.

Comment: @callculus I did

Comment: No, you haven´t. Where is the initial value, the change and the resulting loss? You won´t get an appropriate answer if you don´t clarify the situation.

Comment: I seems that you haven´t understood the situation.

Comment: @callculus OK lets say you build porftolio consisting of two stocks. Stock A and Stock B. You do a zero investment portfolio by going long in stock A and short in Stock B. Both have an initial value of 1. If Stock A goes down 50% and stock B goes up 200%, your portfolio return is 50%-200% = -150%

Comment: The problem with your approach is a return of $-12.6\%$ per month equates to a total return of $(1-12.6\%)^6 \approx 44.6\%$, not $-104\%$. The problem is the typical total return formula is $R = (1+r)^n$, and you're going to have issues if you want $R<0$ because an exponential function with a real-valued base and exponent can't have a negative output. I don't know of any standard way to approach this problem.